# Extending component and view in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular11

I stated working on Angular 11. The question is very simple. But I don't find any answer for that. I tried to use OOP concept in Angular. I have a base interface with more than 20 fields.

```
export interface IBaseOperator{
    type:EOperatorType;
    firstname:string;
    lastname:string;
    date:string;
    nic:string;
    // Other field are removed for easiness
}
```

This interface has more than 6 children interface. I don't show all interfaces, but for  Eg

```
export interface IStaff extends IBaseOperator{
    empId:string;
    // some other fields
}

export interface IContractor extends IBaseOperator{
    regId:string;
    joinedDate:string;
    // some other fields
}
```

When I created a view in html for saving, I need to create all `<input>` fields of IBaseOperator and child fields in each components. This leads code duplication of `IBaseOperator` fields in all children. And the same functions for `save(), update(), delete()` for all 6 children will be duplicated. But only different is, some fields needs to be initialized. Currently I'm doing

**For Staff component**

```
this.operatorForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: ['', Validators.required],             // IBaseOpertor
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],              // IBaseOpertor 
      date: ['', Validators.required],                  // IBaseOpertor
      nic: ['', Validators.required],                   // IBaseOpertor
      
      type:[EOperatorType.STAFF,Validators.required]    // IBaseOpertor
      empId: ['', Validators.required]                  // IStaff
    });
```

**For contractor component**

```
this.operatorForm = this.fb.group({
      firstname: ['', Validators.required],             // IBaseOpertor
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],              // IBaseOpertor 
      date: ['', Validators.required],                  // IBaseOpertor
      nic: ['', Validators.required],                   // IBaseOpertor
      
      type:[EOperatorType.CONTRACTOR,Validators.required]   // IBaseOpertor
      regId: ['', Validators.required]                  // IContractor 
      joinedDate: ['', Validators.required]             // IContractor 
    });
```

I found some problems here

1. Code duplication in all 6 html files and ts files
2. If I need to change in IBaseOperator interface, I need to change in all 6 components.
3. Waste of time and useless codes since code is duplicating.

My question is, is that possible to use inheritance in components (html and ts)? For example :
is that possible to have common `<input>` fields (IBaseOperator) of all children in `BaseComponent.html` and common functions in `BaseComponent.ts`, so when I extend this components, the common fields needs to be inherited from parent component? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option is to create form components representing the fields defined in the interfaces (not including the fields from the interface you're extending). Then in your template(s), compose the form components together to create a complete object.

Comment: This is very-very common problem and lots of frameworks tried to solve it - and still there is no perfect solution. Not sure what u expect as an answer

Comment: How is a contract supposed to lower code duplication? The implementations of said contract should lower code duplication.

Answer (score 1):

Common fields and methods are inherited through the 'extends' keyword

Here's an example of how to extend a formgroup so that you only have to declare a form control once

```
export class ParentComponent {
  form:FormGroup
  date= ''

  commonfunction(){
    
  }
  constructor(protected fb: FormBuilder) {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      date: ['', Validators.required],                  // IBaseOpertor
    })
  }
}
```

```
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  //extends Parent component, so already has 'form' and 'date' properties
  firstname= ''
  lastname= ''
  nic= ''
  empId= ''

  constructor(protected fb: FormBuilder) {
    super(fb) //parentComponent constructor run
    this.commonfunction() //extended from parent
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      ...this.form.controls, //form already initialized because of the call to super()
      firstname: ['', Validators.required],             // IBaseOpertor
      lastname: ['', Validators.required],              // IBaseOpertor
      nic: ['', Validators.required],                   // IBaseOpertor
      empId: ['', Validators.required]                  // IStaff
    });
  }
}
```

In the child component, the form property also has the control for 'date' because of the use of [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) above ("...this.form.controls")

Comment: This is what I try to do, before that I have a question. Why **firstname, lastname and nic** need to be initialized in child component since they are parent's property?

Comment: If they are initialized in the parent they won't have to be initialized in the child. Sorry, I just took random properties from your example without looking at which is the child and which is in the parent. If you swapped the properties it would still work.

Answer (score 0):

so basically you need to display an editable form. you could use https://formly.dev/ui/material (or other alternatives) for the form, and pass different fields (in addition to a set of common ones) as an input to a generic component displaying the form. It's composition instead of inheritance - still pretty much OOP.